# Получение данных в виде xml и запись в xml файл

Tags: python, xml, файлы, url

Укажите, пожалуйста, где почерпнуть мудрости. С помощью python (использую 3.7) нужно сделать url запрос, получить данные в виде xml и сохранить в xml файл. Почему вот так получается:

```
response = requests.get('url')
with open('file.xml', 'wb') as file:
    file.write(response.content)
```

А без метода b xml файл оказывается некорректным?

Comment: Не ясно, какой язык программирования вы используете. Пожалуйста уточни.

Comment: Использую python 3.7